# Is this a good way to finish a PhD current status conference?

Tags: phd, conference, writing-style

First of all sorry if I commit any mistake in this question, I read all the instructions but it´s my first one on this useful site:

I am finishing some diapositives for a PhD current status conference, and I thought about these image as the last one:

---

```
                                     **Thank you and...**
```

[image]

---

I know it is a good technique to end a conference by saying something intelligent, funny or nice in order to give the audience one last "good feeling" so a good impression is left, but I don´t want it to be seen as immature.

Thanks in advance to everyone.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by to end a conference?  Do you mean ending your own oral presentation, or are you hosting an (internal?) conference of some kind?

Comment: This is my first PhD year, and I have to explain what I´ve done during the year in a conference. It´s not an internal one as long everyone can attend. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A problem with that kind of ending is that the last slide tends to be shown the longest, because of the upcoming questions section, and it's somewhat distracting to ask with a funny picture behind. Something an instructor told me long time ago, for any slightly formal presentation, is to just show the first slide again (the title slide), so that you can answer questions with just the title of the talk behind you, avoiding distraction.

Comment: Really useful answer, buddy. Do you add any kind of "Q&A" word in the repeated title slide?

Comment: @stackman Nope. They should be thanking me for giving them a piece of my vast knowledge (?). Anyways, see my edit, I don't like those one-word slides that say "thank you" or "questions".

Comment: The last line of your answer should be "any questions?" :)

Comment: Excellent and insightful response. I never liked the final slide "Any Questions?" that people tend to show but never new why. Thanks for explaining my own dislike to me :-)

Answer (score 1):

first of: I would be very suprised if that image (maybe even phrase) hasn't got copyright/tradmark connected to it and I would think more than twice before using it.

Secondly: I second the suggestion given above to just repeat the first slide. It will also help people remember what you're actually talking about if for instance your presentation has a very long/boring/complex name.